# Excluding Sundays in from below formulae

Tags: excel, excel-formula, calculation

How can I exclude Sundays from the formulae below which i got from this forum? Scott generated the formulae.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(ROW(INDIRECT($A2 & ":" & IF($B2="",TODAY(),B2))))=MONTH(C$1)))
```

Comment: Check out networkdays.intl() and look at setting the days argument.

Comment: It would ne nice to know what a2, B2 were referring to .(or at least a reference to where in 'this forum' you got this equation...

Comment: Thank you for responding. A2 is the start date, and B2 is the end date.

Comment: No prob- don't forget to vote! :)

Comment: Hello James, absolutely the vote will come. Just to mention to you that the answer you gave did not work.

Comment: The initial calculation I shared works better then two dates. What I want is to get number of days excluding Sundays and be able to transpose the formulas across the months.

Answer (score 0):

Place a condition in the sumproduct, for instance:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(ROW(INDIRECT($A2 & ":" & IF($B2="",TODAY(),B2))))=MONTH(C$1)),1* (weekday(date_column_cell) <>  1)
```

Ta,

Comment: Thank you for the feedback James. Kindly let me know what date column are you referring in the formulae "(date_column_cell)"

Comment: I am here dealing with two dates, i.e.A2 is the start date, and B2 is the end date